# how to insert into the singly linked list using double pointers?

Tags: c, linked-list

[codepad link](http://codepad.org/NyUITHU3)[image]I'm trying to insert into a linked list using double pointers.but i don't understand where i'm going wrong i followed up other links on stack overflow,i even referred to couple of books so please help me.i kept code for insertion at position 1.In the output the previous insertion is lost.

```
struct node
{
         int data;
         node *next;
};

 void insert(node **head,int k,int pos)//k refers to the element to be inserted
{
   if(pos==1)
   {
    node *newnode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data=k;
    newnode->next=*head;
    *head=newnode;
   }
 }

   void print(node **head)
  {
    printf("the elements are.. ");
    while(*head!=NULL)
    {
      printf("%d ",(*head)->data);
     (*head)=(*head)->next;
    }
   printf("\n");
  }
   int main()
   {
        insert(&head,5,1);
        print(&head);
        insert(&head,4,1);
        print(&head);
      return 0;
  }
```

sorry for poor indentation.i'm beginner please help me.

Comment: This isn't valid C code. Please post, via copy & paste, the *actual* code you are compiling and running. Also, *tell us in what way it isn't working*.

Comment: Maybe this explains what you are looking for: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html

Comment: Why not bung it into codepad.org or similar?

Comment: @JimBalter i made few changes to the code

Comment: @EdHeal i added codepad link

Comment: Minor issue: you should be using `size_t pos`. Otherwise someone could do `insert(&list, 16, -18)` or something similar. If they do that, they will get a warning about a difference in signedness if they compile with a reasonable warning level. Whether they do or do not, it is just ignorance on their part to pass a negative number to the function, but using `size_t` can at least warn them.

Comment: The `if` in the `insert` function is redundant this case. You are throwing away the previous value of `head`

Comment: @ChronoKitsune i'm learner i didnot understand what you explained in your comment can you give me a link or sample for your explanation

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type, so it can only use nonnegative numbers. If you use `size_t pos` instead of `int pos` and a number such as -842 is passed to the `insert` function as the position, a warning can be displayed. It would be somebody else's fault that they didn't take the hint given when `size_t` was used.

Comment: @EdHeal i will handle that one i will remove if and implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print function is incorrect. You are erasing your head in line `(*head)=(*head)->next;`. Change function to

```
void print(node **head)
  {
    printf("the elements are.. ");
    node *temp = *head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
      printf("%d ",temp->data);
     temp=temp->next;
    }
   printf("\n");
  }
```

You will receive following output:

> the elements are.. 5
>   the elements are.. 4 5

Comment: can you please explain me why the head is not going to the next position

Comment: It goes. But new value is assigned to head. So when you are calling `print(&head);` second time you receive incorrect results.

Comment: so i'm modifying the actual pointer thanks a lot for identifying the mistake

Comment: You can add `cout<<head<<endl;` after first and second `print(&head);` to check your `head`. It should not change!.

Comment: from next time i will do it

Comment: This is C ... there's no such thing as cout.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
struct node //Missed struct's name
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void insert(node **head,int k,int pos)//k refers to the element to be inserted
{
    if(pos==1)
    {
        node *newnode= new node();
        newnode->data=k;
        newnode->next=*head; //You called head which is not a member of node's struct
        *head=newnode;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *head=NULL;
    insert(&head,5,1);
    insert(&head,4,1);
}
```

Comment: *head i'm passing in the function and in c++ we can omit struct word right?? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: No, we cannot.
&

You can't do this in C++:

-Calling the struct's member "*head" without instance

-Unnamed struct:

struct{
....
}

-Struct is not followed by a semicolon

-*head = news, where news wasn't defined anywhere

What you did good was:
-Passing a pointer to list's head, not the head itself:
 you passed Node** head instead of Node* head.

Comment: i think we can do once check out this link its compiling http://codepad.org/NyUITHU3

Comment: I checked it, it's correct
In the old code
You defined struct's member "head"
and called newnode->next (doesn't exist) when I changed the node's member name to next , the head (didn't exist) <I made a mistake calling for head instead of next>

Comment: oh i'm sorry it was my mistake